# Restricting tasks within block to specific worker(s)

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

Currently have a problem where I would like to constrain all calls to `compute`, `persist`, etc. within a block of code to run on worker(s) with specific resources. Unfortunately don't have access to the calls to `compute` myself. Is it possible to apply this constraint using `dask.config.set` using the context manager syntax or some other equally effective mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

As of 2018-07-02 no, this is not supported.  It does seem like a reasonable request though.